# PostgreSQL , CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

i have query

```
select case
  when (status = 'MENANG' is null ) then '0'
  when (status = 'KALAH' is null) then '0'
  when (status = 'PROSES' is null) then '0'
  when (status = 'BATAL' is null) then '0'
  when (status = 'MUNDUR' is null) then '0'
  else status 
  end as data_status,
  count(a.kode_barang) as total 
  from tbl barang 
  group by status
```

here I have a query and some status,
here I use the count to calculate the number of items based on status

when run,

```
data_status | jumlah (count)
KALAH              2
kosong             4
MENANG             2
PROSES             11
```

how to display all status data, including status data whose value is 0 or null

Comment: What would you like to see instead?

Comment: as show i want to return value 0

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all the possible values for `status`?

Comment: the table above with the status 'MUNDUR' does not exist, therefore I want to display the status 'MUNDUR' = 0

Comment: manual data from the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a table that contains all possible values for `status` you can use a `VALUES` list and a LEFT JOIN:

```
select v.status, 
       count(b.status) as total
from ( 
      values ('MENANG', 'KALAH', 'PROSES', 'BATAL', 'MUNDUR')
  ) as v(status)
  left join barang b on b.status = v.status
group by v.status
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of possible statuses available in a table you just need to  join with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

If your `list_of_status` table is is:

```
create table list_of_status (status varchar);
insert into  list_of_status values('MENANG');
insert into  list_of_status values('KALAH');
insert into  list_of_status values('PROSES');
insert into  list_of_status values('BATAL');
insert into  list_of_status values('MUNDUR');
```

and your `data_status` is

```
create table data_status (status varchar,kode_barang int);
insert into data_status values ('MENANG',3);
insert into data_status values ('KALAH',2);
insert into data_status values ('PROSES',3);
insert into data_status values ('MENANG',3);
```

```
SELECT 
list_of_status.STATUS,
count(kode_barang) as total 
FROM list_of_status LEFT OUTER JOIN data_status ON list_of_status.STATUS= data_status.STATUS
group by list_of_status.STATUS
```

with the expected result of

```
 status | total 
--------+-------
 KALAH  |     1
 BATAL  |     0
 MENANG |     2
 PROSES |     1
 MUNDUR |     0
(5 rows)
```

If you want all the statuses in th `list_of_status` table **PLUS** any other status present in the `data_status` you can achieve it with a `FULL_OUTER_JOIN`.

e.g. if we include in the `data_status` a row for `TEST` status not available in `list_of_status` with

```
insert into data_status values ('TEST',5);
```

The following query returns the desired result including the `TEST` row

```
select
COALESCE(list_of_status.STATUS, data_status.STATUS) STATUS,
count(kode_barang) as total 
FROM list_of_status FULL OUTER JOIN data_status ON list_of_status.STATUS= data_status.STATUS
group by COALESCE(list_of_status.STATUS, data_status.STATUS)
```

Result:

```
 status | total 
--------+-------
 TEST   |     1
 MUNDUR |     0
 MENANG |     2
 PROSES |     1
 KALAH  |     1
 BATAL  |     0
(6 rows)
```